# How can I get response from servlet using ajax after sending data to that servlet?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, servlets

I have 2 arrays that I need for my JSP. I sent the user's input from the first input tag to the Servlet and i want to return an array who's values depend on what the user has entered but for testing i thought I'd send a normal string and to print it in the console but for some reason it doesn't work. When I go to the network tab in the **Inspect Element** I see that i got a **POST** response from the Servlet but nothing shows up in the console.

Here's my JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="createFlight">
    <div>
        <input name="car" list="anrede" id="country" onchange="console.log(this.value)">
        <datalist id="anrede"></datalist>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
var countries = ["French Polynesia", "Algeria", "Denmark", "South Africa", "United Arab Emirates", "Russia", "China", "Brazil", "Yemen", "Russian Federation", "Spain", "Iran", "United States", "Ivory Coast", "Ethiopia", "Australia", "Egypt", "Saudi Arabia", "Nigeria", "United Kingdom", "Mexico", "Ghana", "Switzerland", "Turkey", "Jordan", "Colombia", "Chad", "Argentina", "Norway", "Iceland", "Uzbekistan", "Solomon Islands", "Morocco", "France", "Sweden", "Papua New Guinea", "Greenland", "India", "Paraguay", "Venezuela", "Italy", "Honduras", "Cook Islands", "Comoros", "Libya", "Japan", "New Zealand", "Canada", "Kazakhstan", "Myanmar", "Syria", "Indonesia", "Netherlands", "Madagascar", "Chile", "Belgium", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Germany", "Greece", "Malaysia", "Mozambique", "Samoa", "Peru", "Tanzania", "Romania", "Turkmenistan", "Bahamas", "St. Helena", "Eritrea", "Kenya", "Sudan", "Mauritania", "Aruba", "Vanuatu", "Anguilla", "Dominican Republic", "Philippines", "Bahrain", "Botswana", "Somalia", "Cuba", "Costa Rica", "Bermuda", "Nepal", "Serbia", "Lebanon", "Thailand", "Central African Republic", "Barbados", "Iraq", "Pakistan", "Marshall Islands", "Gambia", "Burundi", "Mali", "Congo", "Malawi", "Vietnam", "New Caledonia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Panama", "Bulgaria", "Netherlands Antilles", "Burkina Faso", "Czech Republic", "Equatorial Guinea", "Slovakia", "Hungary", "Zimbabwe", "Georgia", "Cape Verde", "Croatia", "Brunei", "Mongolia", "Belize", "Poland", "Bangladesh", "Angola", "Haiti", "French Guiana", "Bolivia", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Ireland", "Zambia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "South Korea", "Guinea", "Sri Lanka", "Benin", "Senegal", "Ecuador", "Portugal", "Ukraine", "Kiribati", "Cayman Islands", "Taiwan", "Dominica", "Tunisia", "Cameroon", "Qatar", "Tajikistan", "Mayotte", "Uganda", "Cyprus", "British Virgin Islands", "null", "Finland", "Namibia", "Israel", "Tonga", "Armenia", "Faroe Islands", "Martinique", "Democratic Republic of Congo", "Sierra Leone", "North Korea", "Guatemala", "Kyrgyzstan", "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "Tuvalu", "Wallis and Futuna Islands", "Maldives", "Gabon", "Guadeloupe", "Turks And Caicos Islands", "Guyana", "Gibraltar", "Grenada", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Afghanistan", "Hong Kong", "Lao People's Democratic Republic", "Fiji", "Nauru", "Niue", "Djibouti", "Estonia", "Rwanda", "Oman", "Jamaica", "Moldova", "Federated States of Micronesia", "Lithuania", "Kuwait", "Togo", "Slovenia", "Laos", "Latvia", "Luxembourg", "Monaco", "Macau", "Nicaragua", "Belarus", "Malta", "Liberia", "Falkland Islands", "Mauritius", "Lesotho", "Swaziland", "Uruguay", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Niger", "Norfolk Island", "Cote D'Ivoire", "Macedonia", "Guinea-Bissau", "Cambodia", "Bhutan", "Suriname", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Seychelles", "Palau", "Reunion", "El Salvador", "Singapore", "St. Lucia", "Montenegro", "Albania", "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Antarctica", "Western Sahara", "Christmas Island", "Macao"];
var options = '';

for(var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++)
  options += '<option value="'+countries[i]+'" />';

document.getElementById('anrede').innerHTML = options;
var newVal;
$("#country").change(function(){
    newVal= $(this).val();
    console.log("new VAL is: "+newVal); 
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'foundCountry',
        data: {newVal: newVal},
        success: function() {console.log('SENT');}
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my Servlet:

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/foundCountry")
public class foundCountry extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;   
    public foundCountry() {
        super();
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("newVal"));
        String newVal = request.getParameter("newVal");
        response.getWriter().write(newVal+ "  ree");
    }
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but shouldn't `data` be a JSON string, not an object?

Comment: remove `onchange="console.log(this.value)"` this line from your `<input..>` .